# Left outer join and OR clause is slow. Is it possible to join after filtering?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables like below. (1 million records in each table) When I join the two table and execute a query with OR clause, it is very slow. Is it possible that  join the 2 tables ?

```
1. tblA

id | name
---------------------
1  | Bob
2  | carol

2. tblB

id | name
---------------------
1  | Alice
2  | carol
```

This is very slow. (or timeout error occur)

```
select * from `tblA` left outer join `tblB` on `tblA`.`name` = `tblB`.`name` where `tblA`.`name` = 'Alice' or `tblB`.`name` = 'Alice'
```

Each query are not slow.

```
select * from `tblA` left outer join `tblB` on `tblA`.`name` = `tblB`.`name` where `tblA`.`name` = 'Alice'
select * from `tblA` left outer join `tblB` on `tblA`.`name` = `tblB`.`name` where `tblB`.`name` = 'Alice'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `union all`:

```
select *
from `tblA` a left outer join
     `tblB` b
      on a.name = b.name
where a.name = 'Alice'
union all 
select *
from `tblA` a inner join
     `tblB` b
      on a.name = b.name
where b.name = 'Alice' and a.name <> 'Alice'  -- got it in the first query;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union`

```
select * from `tblA` where `name` = 'Alice'
union all
select * from `tblB` where `name` = 'Alice'
```

Comment: You are assuming that the columns in `tblA` and `tblB` are the same.  That doesn't seem reasonable in a real situation -- plus this returns 2 columns whereas the OPs query returns 4.